# Why is this JavaScript method outperforming my C# method?

Tags: c#, list, performance, .net-core

I'm currently testing the performance of certain list operations in both `C#` and `JavaScript` to determine the gap between the two of them.

Currently, I was testing the speed of adding an element to a list in both `C#` and `JavaScript`. Here I found out that somehow JavaScript managed to outperform `C#`, although my research beforehand showed that `C#` should be quite a bit faster.

`C#:`

```
            var time = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var loops = 10000000;
            var strList = new List<string>();
            time.Start();
            for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++)
            {
                strList.Add("Loop" + i);
            }
            time.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("TIME: " + time.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
```

`JS:`

```
    var t0 = performance.now();
    var loops = 10000000
    strList = []
    for(var i = 0; i < loops; i++)
    {
        strList.push("Loop" + i);
    }
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log("TIME: " + (t1-t0) + "ms");
```

I noticed that, when I replaced the `strList.push("Loop" + i);` function in both languages to `strList.push("Loop")` (without the index), the performance went up by an enormous amount.

`With index:`
`C#`:
-3805ms

`JavaScript`:
- Chrome: 6048ms
- Firefox: 1248ms

`Without index:`
`C#`:
-166ms

`JavaScript`:
- Chrome: 348ms
- Firefox: 154ms

Summed up, my question is: why is C# under performing JavaScript when the JS is run on Firefox? And why does adding the index to the list cause for such an extreme decrease in performance? Is there another method to perform this faster?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"Loop" + i` is a string concatenation, in both languages.  That's going to take some time.

Comment: But when replacing the for loop by: 
```C# 
string x = "Loop" + i;
strList.Add("Loop");
```
The code only takes 900 ms (while still performing the concatenation)

Comment: You can pre-set the list capacity with `new List<string>(loops)` or `strList.Capacity = loops;`

Comment: your JavaScript tests should run in node environment not in a browser:
I run those test and this is the result:
Chrome 9000ms NodeJs 3900 ms

Comment: The problem is not the time the string concatenation takes, but the memory allocation for those strings. It will allocate 10 million strings! This gives the garabage collector a lot of work!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes But please why the JavaScript code is faster?

Comment: You might get a part of the answer here: [The Baseline Interpreter: a faster JS interpreter in Firefox 70](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/08/the-baseline-interpreter-a-faster-js-interpreter-in-firefox-70/). Also, make sure to run your C# code in **Release** mode (not Debug mode).

Comment: I was running this in release, yes. And I care to know this information as I'm considering my possibilities for a new project, which will be using electron.NET. So for this use case, but also regular ASP.NET with JS design choices can depend on the performance of the two. E.g. should I apply client side filtering of data, or can this possibly be outperformed server side, etc.

Comment: The performance of client side filtering vs server side filtering (which will be massively impacted by latency and network speed, for example) is a completely different problem to 'how well does this runtime handle large numbers of strings being allocated and concatenated to a list'. Almost every language / runtime will do _something_ faster than another language (even if the latter language is _generally_ faster than the first). But if you want to compare two different languages - you should compare them _in the context of the problem you are trying to solve._

Comment: I suggest to read this article. It explains why JS is faster https://codeburst.io/node-js-v8-internals-an-illustrative-primer-83766e983bf6 CLR transforms source code into bytecode (CIL) which runs in this (VM) whereas JavaScript is compiled to native machine code.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting I did some checks and found your statement to match my findings (the C# implementation is slower). As far as I can explain the allocation of the target collection and the setting of the new value in the loop are a bit redundant and that swallows the time. Also, your variation with or without the index in the loop name is slower because the string has to be created again, although string.format or string.concat didn't make any difference. Still, I'm no Jon Skeet and I do like to know the exact reason.

If you consider a LINQ approach, my new time was around 12 milliseconds

```
  var time = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var loops = 10000000; 
    time.Start();
    var strList = Enumerable.Range(0, loops).Select(i => $"Loop{i}");

    time.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("TIME: " + time.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
```

Comment: AFAIK Linq statements are fairly lazy - if you add a `ToList()` to that, the performance will likely be quite different...

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried your LINQ approach, however when using `ToList()` to finalize it, the execution time also ended up at around 4000ms unfortunately.

Comment: Note that `var strList = Enumerable.Range(0, loops).Select(i => $"Loop{i}");` only prepares the enumeration. It is **not** executed! To execute it you must foreach it or execute `ToList` or the like.